# Select value of a column based on another column min(date) with Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Let say I have the following table :

```
AccountID   Email              status_update       date (dd/mm/yyyy) 
123456      foo@gmail.com      state1              02/02/2016
123456      foo@gmail.com      state2              10/010/2018
456123      bar@gmail.com      state2              05/04/2017
789123      foobar@gmail.com   state2              22/04/2016
789123      foobar@gmail.com   state1              17/06/2018
456345      cool@gmail.com     state1              13/08/2017
456345      cool@gmail.com     state2              09/07/2015
456345      cool@gmail.com     state2              09/07/2014
```

here is the output I want :

```
UniqueID    Email              Most_recent_status_Update  CountUniqueID                    
123456      foo@gmail.com      state2                     2
456123      bar@gmail.com      state2                     1    
789123      foobar@gmail.com   state1                     2              
456345      cool@gmail.com     state1                     3
```

So basically I want to be able to `group by Email`, to do a `unique(AccountID)` and to select `status_update` based in `MIN(date)`

The difficult part to me is being able to select `status_update` based in `MIN(date)`. I would like to be able to do something like this :

`Select status_update when date = min(date)`

I'm thinking about using `CASE` formula in order to have something like this :

`Select CASE (WHEN date = min(date) Then status_update else null END`

I always end up with all kind of error. I'm not able to build the whole query.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See example below  - for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 123456 accountID, 'foo@gmail.com' email, 'state1' status_update, '02/02/2016' dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 123456, 'foo@gmail.com', 'state2', '10/10/2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 456123, 'bar@gmail.com', 'state2', '05/04/2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT 789123, 'foobar@gmail.com', 'state2', '22/04/2016' UNION ALL
  SELECT 789123, 'foobar@gmail.com', 'state1', '17/06/2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 456345, 'cool@gmail.com', 'state1', '13/08/2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT 456345, 'cool@gmail.com', 'state2', '09/07/2015' UNION ALL
  SELECT 456345, 'cool@gmail.com', 'state2', '09/07/2014' 
)
SELECT 
  accountID, 
  email, 
  ARRAY_AGG(status_update ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt) DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET (0)] most_recent_status_update,
  COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY accountID, email
```

with result as

```sql
Row accountID   email               most_recent_status_update   cnt  
1   456123      bar@gmail.com       state2                      1    
2   123456      foo@gmail.com       state2                      2    
3   789123      foobar@gmail.com    state1                      2    
4   456345      cool@gmail.com      state1                      3
```

for your real use case you should use something like below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  accountID, 
  email, 
  ARRAY_AGG(status_update ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt) DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET (0)] most_recent_status_update,
  COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY accountID, email
```

Note: this example assumes specific schema / data types (based on your example in question)  - so if your real datatypes are different  - you need to adjust things a little :o)

Comment: thx. However this doesn't apply when you have thousand rows or I'm missing something...

Comment: just remove whole WITH statement and use your specific table name instead \`project.dataset.table`  :o)  Try and let know. Also I added this to the answer

Comment: thanks. I don't understand how does the count work. what does count(1) mean ?

Comment: count(1) just counts number of rows in given group. i didn't know what exactly you needed there  - so just added it here

Comment: I just wanted to count the number of uniqueID. thanks. Another question. If I understand well I just need to change DESC by ASC if I want not the Most recent status update but the oldest. right ?

Comment: and last question, is there a way to do this with Legacy SQL ?

Comment: 1) BQ legacy SQL doesn't even support arrays function 2) BigQuery Team is strongly recommending using BQ standard SQL 3) technically - almost anything can be done in both dialects - so if you really really need this in legacy SQL - you can post new question and someone (myself including) potentially will answer it :o)